# Convert text number composed of 2 different numbers to digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numbers

I have been trying to find a solution to my problem but in vain.

I have a data base of numbers that can be divided into 2 types of written numbers to convert: I want to be able to **detect** which type of sentence I am dealing with it and then do the **conversion**.

**1. Normal one**, where I simply use `text2num()` function for the conversion:

Example:

```py
number = "one hundred fourty five"
print(text2num(number, "en"))
```

my output is

```
>>>145
```

---

**2. Second type, is made up of two different numbers:**

My input would be a little something like this:

```py
number = "thirty six seventy two"
number2 = "eighty two fifty"
```

And I am trying to get the following:

```
>>>number="3672"
>>>number2="8250"
```

> *To be clearer: if my sentences are like the following:*

```py
"thirty two eighty"
"five hundred eighty"
"ten zero eight"
```

My output should be like this:

```
"3280"
"580"
"1008"
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like its submodule `alpha2digit` does support it, you just need to further `split` and `join` the result to get the expected output:

```
from text_to_num import alpha2digit

''.join(alpha2digit("thirty six seventy two", lang='en').split())
# '3672'

''.join(alpha2digit("eighty two fifty", lang='en').split())
# '8250'
```